# How to overwrite a .docx file using openxml in visual studio?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have created a word file using openxml in visualstudio. But I want to overwrite the file. How should I proceed?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far and what went wrong? Is there not a "Save" method in the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear to me. So I decided to give you a starting point:

```
public void YourAwesomeMethod()
{
       WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create("path", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

       // do all the crazy stuff with your document...

       wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save(); // save it!
}
```